# How to seed a complete torrent

Tags: bittorrent

I have a .iso file and I am keen on to seed it.

also I have the related torrent file!

which torrent client could  do this?

Comment: What torrent client are you using?

Comment: i use Transmission and aria2. but both of them couldn't do this!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work with Transmission. I don't think it will work with aria.

Start the torrent downloading it(you don't need to have a seeder around) and then stop it. Quit the torrent program. Go to the file in progress of downloading, and replace it with your completed file. Open the torrent client and right-click the torrent, and use the option to do a full recheck. Once that finishes, it will change to 100%. Start the torrent and it will seed.

Answer (score 3):

If you don't want to use Transmission: Use qBittorrent.

Comment: Greatest torrent client ever.